# Join record between table only once in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have `tbl1` Structured like this

```
Name         Type
======        =====
John             1
David            1
Jane             2
William          3
Alex             2
Ryan             1
```

And `tbl2` structured like this

```
Index   Type     Job
  1       1      Clean
  2       1      Wash
  3       2      Carry
  4       2      Package
  5       3      Sell
```

I would like to join record with matched `Type`, but each record in `tbl1` only join once with one record in `tbl2`

Ie:

If
`John` is joined with `Clean` then `David` must be joined with `Wash`. Or if `John` is joined with `Wash` then `David` must be joined with `Clean`.

Doesn't matter if `David` is joined with `Wash` or `Clean` , I only need them to be joined with record that match the criteria and be joined ONCE.

I will make sure for each `Type` in 'tbl1' there will be equivalent amount of record in 'tbl2'

I mainly work on MS Access so Query on this environment would be the best~ Thank you all for reading.

Best regards

Comment: There seems to be a redundant record in `tbl1`. What do you want to do with this record?

Comment: If this is not Sql Server then remove the tag.

Comment: You also have "Ryan" with `type=1` in  `tbl1`. So, what is expected relations for that row with `tbl2`?

Comment: Yes for that if it can display `Null` for "Ryan" it's the best, but otherwise I would go to make sure there is another `type=1` Record in `tbl2` to match with the amount in `tbl1`

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
select name, (select TOP(1) job from tbl2 where tbl1.type = tbl2.type) from tbl1
```

Hope it help

Comment: The sub-select doesn't select anything.

Comment: This query made both "John" and "david" and "ryan" match with "clean"

Comment: John, david and ryan type is 1 which is Clean. You said that Doesn't matter if David is joined with Wash or Clean , I only need them to be joined with record that match the criteria and be joined ONCE.

Comment: I mean if `John` DID joined with `Clean`, then `David` CANNOT join with `Clean` and have to join with other option, which is `Wash`. I mean It doesn't matter if it's : John - Clean, David-Wash OR John - Wash, David - Clean

Comment: i see. Then the easiest way is to have rank column so you can compare it by rank to avoid duplication. The mapping table itself already a problem since a single type having more than 1 value. its violating the key values mapping.